# How to grep for two strings using os.system()

Tags: python, grep

How do we grep for two strings using `os.system()`?

The following commands fails:

```
os.system("grep " + "Section\|Function"   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
```

Comment: Doesn't display the output. Output is empty

Comment: There are better ways to do this directly in Python. Why not just write Python?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the options that work. @mata gave you a nice list of more possibilities.

```
os.system("grep -E 'Section|Function' " + Text_file + "> results.csv")
```

So, for sure you need an extra space after "Function".
Besides, to search for multiple strings, one option is the `-E` flag which allows for extended regular expressions in the search criteria.

Comment: There is no error in the output but the results are not printed as well.When I run the grep command separately , it works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to grok the string if one uses python's string formatting rather than `+`:

```
os.system("grep -E 'Section|Function' {} > results.csv".format(Text_file))
```

The `-E` enables extended regex.  This eliminates the need for `grep` to see an escaped vertical bar.

When you run this command, it passes through three stages: python, bash, and grep.  The command string has to be designed with all three stages in mind.  Note that the python string is enclosed in double-quotes.  In python, there is not difference in meaning between double and single quotes.  In `bash`, there is an important difference.  Because  the python string is enclosed in double-quotes, we can put single-quotes around the regex inside it.  When `bash` sees the single quotes, it leaves the regex alone.  In this way, the regex we see in python will be the same as the regex passed to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash in your pattern just prevents the shell to interpret the pipe symbol, `grep` in this case sees `Section|Function`. `grep` in default mode does not interpret the pipe as `OR`, but as literal pipe, only in extended mode (using the `-E` flag) it is interpreted as `OR`, in default mode you need to escape it with another backslash.

And you should use a raw string when you have the escape character (backsalsh) in a string, and also you're missing a space after the second pattern.

So you have a few options, these all should produce the same result:

```
os.system(r"grep Section\\\|Function "   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
os.system(r"grep 'Section\|Function' "   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
os.system(r"grep -E Section\|Function "   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
os.system(r"grep -E 'Section|Function' "   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
os.system(r"grep  -e Section -e Function "   + Text_file +  "> results.csv")
```